# Blender 3.0 shows backface of wireframe (not X-ray), how can I hide back faces?

Tags: wireframe

Blender v3 seemed to change something in the wireframe view where back faces are showing, simlar to X-Ray mode.  Any way to hide / clip back faces in wireframe overlay?

[image]

Comment: when you switch to Wireframe display mode, it will be transparent by default (X-Ray), what happens if you press Alt Z?

Comment: Actually it would be great if you also showed the viewport settings in your screenshot, not only the resulting effect on the objects.

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off X-ray in the Wireframe Viewport Shading:

[image: Xaa]

Comment: Xray is off but the wireframe view is presenting the same effect as X-Ray

Comment: So x-ray does nothing? I dunno - maybe try updating your graphics drivers? Default for me in 3.0 is see through (backface) wireframe with X-ray on - turning off x-ray makes the backfacing wires disappear.